# gcloud translate submitting lists

Tags: python-3.x, gcloud, google-translate

The [codelab example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-translation-python3) for using gcloud translate via python only translates one string:

```
sample_text = "Hello world!"
target_language_code = "tr"
response = client.translate_text(
    contents=[sample_text],
    target_language_code=target_language_code,
    parent=parent,
)

for translation in response.translations:
    print(translation.translated_text)
```

But since it puts sample_text in a list and iterates over the response, I take it one can submit a longer list. Is this true and can I count on the items in the response corresponding to the order of items in contents? This must be the case but I can't find a clear answer in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

- [translate_text](https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/translate_v3/translation_service.html?highlight=translate_text#google.cloud.translate_v3.services.translation_service.TranslationServiceAsyncClient.translate_text) `contents` is a `Sequence[str]` but must be less than 30k (codepoints).
- For longer than 30k, use [batch_translate_text](https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/translate_v3/translation_service.html?highlight=batch_translate_text#google.cloud.translate_v3.services.translation_service.TranslationServiceClient.batch_translate_text)
- [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) provides an explanation of the request and response types for the [translateText](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations/translateText) method. This allows you to call the underlying REST API method and it generates a 'form' for you in which `content` is an array of string (as expected).
- The [TranslateTextResponse](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/TranslateTextResponse) describes `translations` as having the same length as `contents`.
- There's no obvious other way  to map entries in `contents` with `translations` so these must be in the same order, `translations[foo]` being the translation of `contents[foo]`.

You can prove this to yourself by:

1. making the call with multiple known translations
2. including one word not in the source language (i.e. `notknowninenglish` in English) to confirm the translation result.